# Provide value to JSON's attribute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON structure inside my code, I would like to pass a value to one of the attributes. Problem is I do not know how to do this? Since it is one whole string in C#, what is the possible way to achieve this?

For example, I want to pass the string appName to the JSON's AppName. How do I do this?

```
IEnumerator Start(){
  var appName = "Testing001";

  var json = @"{
        'values': {
        'AppName': '',
        'Time': '23:15',
        }
            }";

        var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (json);

        using (var www = new UnityWebRequest (url, "POST")) {
            www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw (jsonBytes);
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer ();
            www.SetRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
            www.SetRequestHeader ("Accept", "text/plain");

            yield return www.SendWebRequest ();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
                Debug.Log (www.error);
            } else {
                Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log (www.error);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your JSON is **invalid**. single quotes are not allowed, please use double quotes. also: welcome to stackoverflow. 
what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: and in general, the best way to generate, parse or manipulate JSON is using one of the already existing and free json converters that are basically shipped with almost every language/framework - dotnet included.

Comment: But my JSON works. I actually send the data to server using UnityWebRequest. Could you please explain where I should use double quotes? Because I tried using and it threw errors.

Comment: How are you sending the data? Show that code. You should probably use a proper C# class to create your structure and then convert that to JSON. Doing it manually isn't trivial.

Comment: JSON ___requires___ double quotes around strings and property names, anything else is invalid. As others have said (many times probably) there's no reason to manually write JSON like this.

Comment: @phuzi what would be the proper way to write then? Could you please post an answer/solution?

Comment: @Rein if your JSON works, that's because the server is _too_ forgiving. but it's still invalid. as to where: everywhere you use a single quote? and i already told you what the proper way of writing is: using an existing json converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** I'm not familiar with the peculiarities of Unity

So you want to create some JSON using variable values do you?

As others (and myself) have said in the comments, you should never create JSON manually as it is so easy to make a small mistake and end up with invalid JSON.

You will either want to use rigid model classes, or in a pinch, an anonymous type.

```cs
var appName = "Testing001";

// create our model as an anonymous type using the `appName` variable value.
var model = new {
    values = new {
        AppName = appName,
        Time = "23:15"
    }
};

// Generate valid JSON
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
```

The resulting, valid, JSON is

```
{"values":{"AppName":"Testing001","Time":"23:15"}}
```

As you see, property names and strings have double quotes and `AppName` has the  desired value.

**UPDATE - Using A Model Class**

If, for whatever reason, you need/have a model class instead of an anonymous type, you should instantiate that with the necessary values and pass that to the serializer...

Given the model classes `MyModel` and `MyModelValues`

```cs
using System;

[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
    [SerializeField]
    public MyModelValues values;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyModelValues
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string AppName;

    [SerializeField]
    public string Time;
}
```

Then you can substitute the creation of `model` using the model classes.

```cs
// create our model as an anonymous type using the `appName` variable value.
var model = new MyModel
{
    values = new MyModelValues
    {
        AppName = appName,
        Time = "23:15"
    }
};
```

Comment: The JsonSerializer cannot be found is the error I am getting. Should I go for ```JsonUtility.ToJson (model);``` ?

Comment: JsonSerializer is either in System.Text.Json for .Net Core 3+ or Newtonsoft.Json in Json.Net. Either will do for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately JsonSerializer does not work in Unity - https://forum.unity.com/threads/please-add-system-text-json-support.1000369/.

What works is - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Comment: Double checked, and yes, you should be okay with `JsonUtility.ToJson(model)`

Comment: I tried with JsonUtility.ToJson(model) and it only outputs ```{}

Comment: Hmm, you may need to create a simple model class and use that instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: How do I do this? Can you explain with a link?

Comment: @Rein I've updated my answer to include an example using model classes

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I updated my code to your answer and in the end i did ```var json = JsonUtility.ToJson (model);
        Debug.Log (json);``` but still the output is ```{}```

Comment: It seems that there's a separate issue getting that method to generate the correct JSON output. I don't have an environment that would enable me to test locally. Can you reference Json.Net in Unity?

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I found out the issue and I have fixed it in your code. We had to add ```[SerializeField]``` for the variables.

Comment: In that case, it could never work for anonymous types and you would always have to create a model (DTO) class for the serialization with `JsonUtility.ToJson()`